# C'è qualche differenza tra un'asola e un occhiello?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> La piú preziosa virtú di una donna è il sacrificio, e la ricompensa non è di questo mondo, ma il Paradiso eterno. Questo Vita lo sa. E se lo dimentica, glielo ricordano le vicine di casa, che trascorrono giornate interminabili recluse in due stanze a rifilare **asole e occhielli** per la ditta Levy & Co. di Broadway, circondate da un nugolo di creature denutrite che non sanno ancora parlare.

Ho cercato la definizione di "asola" e di "occhiello" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a vedere se ci sia qualche differenza tra loro. Perlomeno nel contesto del brano, i vocabolari sembrano indicare che siano la stessa cosa. È veramente cosí?

Comment: Ho trovato questo link: https://sarapoiese.com/attaccare-bottoni-cucire-asole-un-gioco-ragazzi/. La differenza è davvero minima…

Comment: @Benedetta: Ho letto e riletto l'articolo, ma veramente non riesco a capire qual è la differenza tra asole e occhielli che presumibilmente spiega.

Answer (score 1):

[Asola](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/asola/) e [occhiello](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/occhiello_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/) possono essere considerati sinonimi, come riporta Treccani:

> **occhiello** /o'k:jɛl:o/ s. m. [dim. di occhio]. - 1. [piccolo taglio nella stoffa di un indumento, in cui si fa entrare un bottone] **≈
>   asola.**

Per asola viene riportata una lieve differenza

> **àṡola** s. f. [lat. tardo ansŭla, dim. di ansa «ansa»]. – 1. Anello in cui scorre qualcosa, o in cui s’infila un perno, un gancio, ecc.
>   **2. Più com., orlatura di filo che si fa all’occhiello di un abito, dove si adatta il bottone; e l’occhiello stesso.**

È vero che, se proprio si vuole trovare una differenza seppur minima, normalmente per occhiello si intende l’asola sul bavero della giacca elegante dove usava in passato mettere un fiore.

Il fiore all’occhiello, da cui deriva la famosa [locuzione](https://dizionario.internazionale.it/parola/fiore-allocchiello).